# "Are" vs. "were" when action is in the past, but subject is still extant

Tags: grammaticality

Which is the correct word to use, "are" or "were" (or something else?) in the following examples:

1. Two of the main sources I used for the project are/were Source A and Source B.
2. Three of the ingredients included in the mixture are/were butter, flour and sugar.
3. Two of the augmentations the shop added to this car are/were the canards and the spoiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the present since, as you said, it's still extant.

Comment: But in example #1, the project is complete.  Does that still hold, then?

Answer (score 0):

1. Be consistent. If you say "I used" (past), then use "project were."
2. In my opinion, you could use "are" here because "included" could also be stated as "that are in" or left out entirely.
3. Same as #1: use were.